# jQuery Tabs, how to prevent an anchor jump

Tags: jquery, hash, tabs

I use this script:

```
(function() {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
    tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
        var hash = window.location.hash || '#first';
        tabContainers.hide();
        tabContainers.filter(hash).show();
        $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
        $('a[href=' + hash +']').addClass('selected');
    });
    $(window).trigger("hashchange");
});
```

This part of code gives me everything that i need. To open the tab from the external page i use "index.php#first" href, for example. It opens the page with tabs with the exact tab opened, but it jumps to the anchor, and i need to show the page from it's top.

Does anybody know, how to prevent anchor jumps for this code?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing a `return false` inside the hashchange function?.

Otherwise, you can avoid using real IDs on your elements. That way it will not scroll.

Update: 
As you are using jQuery you can also try with: `e.preventDefault`. The function will need to receive `e` as parameter